# Why the strength of BCryptPasswordEncoder is in between 4 and 31?

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt

According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) :

Implementation of PasswordEncoder that uses the BCrypt strong hashing function. Clients can optionally supply a "strength" (a.k.a. log rounds in BCrypt) and a SecureRandom instance. The larger the strength parameter the more work will have to be done (exponentially) to hash the passwords. The default value is 10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *strength* is translated to iterations. For strength x there will be **2<sup>x</sup>** iterations. Implementations are assumed to use unsigned 32-bit integer, where the maximum value is 4294967295. If x is larger than 31, 2<sup>x</sup> is bigger than this maximum value and an overflow would occur.

In practice, the Java implementation in Spring Security actually uses a 64-bit `long` since integers are *signed* in Java (maximum of `int` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1).

A strength of 31 or close thereof is very slow and not usable anyway.

Comment: Why can't I make it weaker than 4?

Comment: @darw, if i got it, it means not allow secure with 2, 4, 8 interations,